# "Autonomous" power latch circuit triggered by interrupt

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, low-power

I'm trying to design a power latch circuit for a microcontroller. The typical power latch circuit is powered by a button, but I want to power mine with a small accelerometer which sends out an interrupt. The typical power latch circuit also makes the microcontroller power itself. The problem in my scenario: the interrupt is only 3 milliseconds long and the microcontroller needs to long to boot up, meaning I have to rely on other components to keep the power latch high until the microcontroller is powered.
I came up with this circuit so far and wanted to know if it is acceptable or complete garbage :D
[image: Power Latch Circuit that normally "stays on" and is switched off on GPIO HIGH]

The idea behind this is to reverse normal power latch dynamics with the GPIO pins, i.e. the MCU doesn't have to have a HIGH-pin to ensure it is staying enabled, but it only relies on a HIGH-pin for power-off (S1).

Please let me know if this circuit is fine, because I'm pretty much just getting started with all this symbol schematic stuff. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe LT makes a single-chip solution for this sort of thing; the search term you want is "monostable" or perhaps "pulse stretcher".

Answer (score 1):

Probably simplest latch for you purpose is this.
To trig the latch with accelerometer it has to have a push-pull output (not an open-collector).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpSf0H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: i'm trying to simulate this and it seems the only way the N-MOSFET stays on is via the MCU pulling its gate high. Is that the intended & expected behaviour? I feel like it shouldn't be. As a note /& correction: my accelerometer has a 3.3V (VCC) INT pin with configurable push-pull / open-drain.

EDIT: nevermind... i forgot to adjust the MOSFET values. It does work like expected.
EDIT2: I also had to change both R1 and R2 to 100k, otherwise the simulation wouldn't work.

Comment: If accelerometer has open drain you can connect its output to M2 drain to trigger the latch.